# Moving SharePoint 2010 to a new domain

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a small SharePoint 2010 farm (1 WFE / App Server & 1 SQL server)

Our organisation is currently mirgrating to our holding company's global domain, so we now have a new local DC on site with trusts between the current domain and the new domain.

I am going to need to move our SP Farm to the new domain and possibly rename servers to fit into the global naming convention (we are trying to avoid this at the moment, but might become a requirement)

If there a way to script (stsadm / powershell) the user profiles and permission accross to the new domain?  and on the server side, is it as simple as joining the servers to the new domain and updating all the service / farm accounts to accounts on new domain?

I have googled this a bit, but everything I have found so far refers to MOSS 2007 or earlier.

Any help / advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Good question, so if you find out, please post back how you did it. Personally, I would call Microsoft, and spend the $260 rather than risk doing it wrong.

Comment: This is going to be massively complex. I would consider seeing if there is not a possible way for you to keep the old domain alive, migrate the user accounts to the new domain and script the application of permissions based on the user accounts. As KCotreau mentioned this is well worth a call to MS and potentially even spending some cash on a consultant. One thing I can say for sure is this: If you are forced to change the name (meaning unjoin from current domain, join new domain or modify host name) of these servers everything is over.

Answer (score 1):

See here:
[Move SharePoint to a new domain](http://sharepointapplied.com/2009/02/04/move-sharepoint-to-a-new-domain/)

This also might be helpful:
[Move all databases (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx)

I would advise to move it all to new servers, not rename the current enviroment.